# Rails app gets unnecessarily RESTFUL with links

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got an app where the links work fine when I'm on the homepage, but when I'm on a page belonging to a resource such as "users", some links get a little weird.

When I'm on the homepage and I click the link for the "About" page, I'm taken there directly.  But if I'm on the page for users/index and I hover over the link for the "About" page, it shows the destination as being "users/about."

Here's what my routes file looks like.

```
RobotimusApp::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :users

  root to: "pages#home"

  match '/about', to:'pages#about'
  match '/guides', to:'pages#guides'

end
```

Here's what my nav bar looks like

```
%ul.nav
  %li
    =link_to 'Home', root_url
  %li
    =link_to 'About', 'about'
  - if user_signed_in?
    %li
      = link_to('My Sites', user_path(current_user))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welp, the issue lies in this line:

```
=link_to 'About', 'about'
```

Instead of passing in a routed path like `about_path`, we pass in the string `'about'`. When `link_to` receives a string as its URL parameter, it doesn't run it through the router or anything; it assumes that that's the URL you want to go to. (After all, `about_path` and the like return strings.)

So, you end up with something like this in the HTML:

```
<a href="about">About</a>
```

Here, `about` is a relative URL, so from the path `/users` it will go to `/users/about`.

You *could* just use a preceding slash to make it an absolute path:

```
= link_to 'About', '/about'
```

But it's not particularly Rails-y to hard-code our URLs when we can use routes instead. You're probably going for something like this:

```
= link_to 'About', about_pages_path
```

(Is `about_pages` the route name? It probably should be. You can always name it with an `as` parameter.)

Comment: Thanks for the incredibly thorough explanation!

Answer (score 1):

If you run `rake routes` in a terminal you'll get a list of all the routes available.

think  the link for your about page should be

```
  = link_to 'About', about_pages_path
```